# How to change layers in pretrained model in Mxnet

Tags: python, mxnet

I have a pre-trained Mxnet model. I need to change last two layers and add new two layers for testing. Basically, I need to create a probability map of the image.
How can i do that ?

Answer (score 3):

There is a tutorial on fine-tuning with MXNet. Did you check this out? 
http://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/faq/finetune.html